# Flash CS6 actionscript 3.0

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-cs6

I create document 3.0 AC.
I paint circle in 1 frame and symbol "Movieclip" name "circle" and double click,i do create shape tween circle. I write script gotoAndPlay("startcircle") from movieclip "circle",but not working next frame 2 movieclip name "circleup".

First movieclip -> circle begin left run to move right, second movieclip circle run size up circle.

Test movie: First movieclip -> circle begin left run to move right, second movieclip circle not running.

[image]

[image]

Sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your circle needs to tell the thing containing it (its `parent`) to `gotoAndPlay`. This isn't very neat, but you can do:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
(parent as MovieClip).gotoAndPlay("startcircle");
```

(You have to tell Flash the parent is a `MovieClip`, because simpler `DisplayObject`s might not actually have frames to `gotoAndPlay`. If you passed a reference to the parent to circle, you wouldn't need to use `as`.)

Comment: Same not working.

Circle.fla (7 KB)
https://mega.co.nz/#!xVQxBLgS!P173YFKDEd0Yzvri4tMNYVCg2EoYbyD9W1ub-5v4wno

Comment: Ah, sorry. I got the order of your containers mixed up. Try my edited answer?